# In what cases [NSDocument fileURL] can be nil?

Tags: objective-c, nsdocument, nsdocumentcontroller

I'm creating the document with:

```
[NSDocumentController openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:]
```

When I'm working with the instance of `NSDocument` and sometimes I'm getting crashes because `document.fileURL == nil`. What cases in `NSDocument` lifecycle can cause this?

Comment: I can't find `makeDocumentWithContentsOfURL:alternateContents:ofType:completionHandler:` in the documentation. What does parameter `alternateContents` do? What is the return value?

Comment: @Willeke Sorry, I used `openDocumentWithContentsOfURL:display:completionHandler:`. Edited the question.

Comment: Is the document created from a file or are you using a web or any other URL?

Answer (score 1):

`document.fileURL` is `nil` until you save the document for the first time.